# How to escape strings containing keys (when mapping) or call function with noremap

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, buffers

Buffer-specific mappings are supported by vim out of the box. I am trying to implement window-specific mappings. My plan is to override the default keybinding by one that checks if a window-specific map should be executed, if so, it executes that, and if not, execues the default action for that keybinding (this is the `ExecuteWindowMap` function).

I'm having trouble with setting the map, see `SetWindowMap`. This function is called with an argument, `a:map`, a string of keys. It needs to include pass this string of keys to a function call, so it makes sense to use `noremap`; with `map` these keys would get pressed instead of passed to the function! On the other hand, I can only call that function using`<CR>`, which doesn't work with `noremap`!

I see two possible solutions:

1. Use `map` and somehow escape the key sequence contained in `a:map`.
2. Use `noremap` in a way that allows a calling a function.

   ```
   function! SetWindowMap(map)
     exe "noremap " . a:map . " :call ExecuteWindowMap('" . a:map . "')<CR>"
   endfunction

   function! ExecuteWindowMap(map)
     if exists("w:winMaps") && has_key(w:winMaps, a:map)
           exe w:winMaps[a:map]
     else
           exe "unmap " . a:map 
           exe "'a:map'"
           call SetWindowMap(a:map) 
     endif
   endfunction

   function! WindowMap(map, cmd)
     if !exists("w:winMaps")
           let w:winMaps = {}
     endif
     let w:winMaps[a:map] = a:cmd
     call SetWindowMap(a:map)
   endfunction
   ```

Comment: If you did solve your problem, do consider posting an answer instead of deleting the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much time for a serious answer. However, I have many  functions that generate mappings, restore/remove mappings (see `lh#on#exit()`), and so on. For instance, you could have a look at [`lh#menu#map_all()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/menu.vim#L565) and its test case, or lh-bracket [`s:DefineMap()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/autoload/lh/brackets.vim#L329).

Comment: As a side note, your need is quite odd. While I often need modal mappings (that are just defined for the duration of some specific tasks), I don't see a use case where a window mapping could make sense. The task won't be simple as you'll need to restore buffer mappings that you've overridden for the current window.

Answer (score 2):

I was encouraged to answer my own question, I initially deleted it, because I was just not familiar with the way strings work in vim. When you use double quotes, characters preceded by a backslash are escaped before the string is used by the function. You thus need to use double backslashes, or use a literal string with single quotes. It is explained further [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html) and [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html) (Chapter 26 & 31 of Learn Vimscript the Hard Way).

Comment: And your other recently-deleted question about `matchadd` is also an instance of the same quoting problem.